# Error when trying to mount snapshot LVM (XFS filesystem)

Tags: linux, backup, lvm

I have the following logical volume:

```
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/wd1/mongodb
  LV Name                mongodb
  VG Name                wd1
  LV UUID                xxxx
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time xxxx
  LV snapshot status     source of
                         mongodbSnap [active]
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                8.00 GiB
  Current LE             2048
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:3
```

I used the command:

```
lvcreate --size 100M --snapshot --name mongodbSnap /dev/wd1/mongodb
```

to create the following snapshot:

```
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/wd1/mongodbSnap
  LV Name                mongodbSnap
  VG Name                wd1
  LV UUID                xxx
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time xxx
  LV snapshot status     active destination for mongodb
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                8.00 GiB
  Current LE             2048
  COW-table size         100.00 MiB
  COW-table LE           25
  Allocated to snapshot  0.18%
  Snapshot chunk size    4.00 KiB
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:7
```

Everything looks good at this point. However when I try to mount the snap lv volume with the following:

> mount -t xfs /dev/wd1/mongodbSnap /mnt

I get the following error:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/wd1-mongodbSnap,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

### Update

The log message contains the following error:

```
[2424239.516667] XFS (dm-7): Filesystem has duplicate UUID xxxxxx - can't mount
```

Why would the snapshot contain the same UUID as the original lv and how do I get around this? The whole purpose of doing this is to make a backup of the drive using the dd command...

Solution to this is to mount the filesystem with nouuid option

```
mount -o nouuid <source> <dest>
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but you don't need to mount a block device before taking an image of it with dd. In fact, it's better to *not* mount it.

Comment: oh ok thanks for that EEAA i didn't realise that...i thought I had to mount it. What if i wanted to use tar to do an archive file backup though i would need to mount then right?

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no need to mount it for taking a backup with dd. Although dd is not recommended for XFS (see below for why), but if you insist using dd just use the snapshot LV device as the input parameter (`if`):

   ```sh
   dd if=/dev/wd1/mongodbSnap of=/path/backup_of_mongodb_$(date -I).img
   ```
2. UUID is the filesystem's unique identifier which is stored within the filesystem metadata. When you take a snapshot of the LV, also this metadata is identical to the original LV in the snapshot LV and therefore they have the same UUID. However, note what XFS's manual page (locally `man xfs` or online e.g. [here](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/xfs.5.html)) says about its UUIDs:

   > ```
   >   Each XFS filesystem is labeled with a Universal Unique Identifier
   >   (UUID).  The UUID is stored in every allocation group header  and
   >   is  used  to  help  distinguish  one XFS filesystem from another,
   >   therefore you should avoid using dd(1)  or  other  block-by-block
   >   copying programs to copy XFS filesystems.  If two XFS filesystems
   >   on the same machine have the same  UUID,  xfsdump(8)  may  become
   >   confused  when  doing  incremental and resumed dumps.  xfsdump(8)
   >   and xfsrestore(8)  are  recommended  for  making  copies  of  XFS
   >   filesystems.
   > ```

   TLDR: It's better to use xfsdump and xfsrestore.
3. Backing up with xfsdump:

   - Install xfsdump. E.g. in Ubuntu these tools can be installed from the `xfsdump` package:

   ```sh
   apt install xfsdump
   ```

   - Take the dump:

   ```sh
   xfsdump -f /path/backup_of_mongodb_$(date -I).xfsdump /dev/wd1/mongodb
   ```